# Object being disposed when resolving via ToConstant but not when resolving via ToMethod

Tags: c#, ninject

Let's say I have a Ninject kernel, named _kernel, a given object (received as a parameter), say myClass, of type IMyClass:IDisposable; I have noticed that when I bind IMyClass to myClass via ToMethod, like this:

```
Bind<IMyClass>().ToMethod(x => myClass);
```

Then, whenever I dispose the _kernel, `myClass.Dispose()` won't be invoked.

However, if instead I bind IMyClass to myClass via ToConstant, like this:

```
Bind<IMyClass>().ToConstant(myClass);
```

then `myClass.Dispose()` will be invoked when disposing _kernel.

Could you guys explain me this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard scope of `ToConstant` is *Singleton* scope and of `ToMethod` is *Transient* scope. The lifetime of a transient-scoped object is not managed by Ninject, hence the instance is not `Dispose`d.

Comment: @julio.g See also https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes (added a Disposal column with some related info).

Comment: Thanks Remo!
@RubenBartelink: Much clearer for me now, thanks!